# Eclipse Registering Listeners indefinitely

Tags: eclipse, macos

I have **Eclipse Neon.2** running on **MacOS Sierra**.

When I start Eclipse, its progress shows it is "Registering Listeners". This seems to run indefinitely (I have left it for an hour). If I try do any other task like a "Clean", these tasks are put in a queue behind the "Registering Listeners" which never completes.

I can access the Eclipse menus, however if I try click on an installed server, then Eclipse just hangs and is totally unresponsive.

If anyone can suggest a solution, I would appreciate it.

**More info:**

After clicking on a server, and killing the task in the activity Monitor, I get the following report:

```
Date/Time:       2017-01-20 12:03:56 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.12.2 (Build 16C67)
Architecture:    x86_64h
Report Version:  25

Data Source:     Stackshots

Command:         eclipse
Path:            /Users/USER/*/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
Version:         4.6.2 (4.6.2.M20161124-1400)
Parent:          launchd [1]
PID:             1537

Event:           hang
Duration:        2.00s (process was unresponsive for 16 seconds before sampling)
Steps:           20 (100ms sampling interval)

Hardware model:  MacBookPro13,3
Active cpus:     8

Fan speed:       2160 rpm

--------------------------------------------------
Timeline format: stacks are sorted chronologically
Use -i and -heavy to re-report with count sorting
--------------------------------------------------

Heaviest stack for the main thread of the target process:
  20  ??? [0x107ad4704]
  20  ??? [0x1077aa2bd]
  20  ??? [0x1077aa2bd]
  20  ??? [0x1077b9a74]
  20  Unsafe_Park + 126 (libjvm.dylib + 5773339) [0x106d8181b]
  20  Parker::park(bool, long) + 512 (libjvm.dylib + 4747794) [0x106c87212]
  20  __psynch_cvwait + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 105606) [0x7fffac589c86]
 *20  psynch_cvcontinue + 0 (pthread + 39138) [0xffffff7f810c88e2]


Process:         eclipse (Eclipse) [1537]
Path:            /Users/USER/*/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
Architecture:    x86_64
Parent:          launchd [1]
UID:             501
Task size:       1174 MB
Pageins:         1 pages
CPU Time:        0.011
Note:            Unresponsive for 16 seconds before sampling
Note:            3 idle work queue threads omitted

  Thread 0x1d93f            DispatchQueue 1           20 samples (1-20)         priority 46 (base 46)
  <thread QoS user interactive (requested user interactive), process unclamped, process received importance donation from WindowServer [158], process received importance donation from EmojiFunctionRowIM_Extension [403], IO tier 0>
  20  ??? [0x107ad4704] 1-20
    20  ??? [0x1077aa2bd] 1-20
      20  ??? [0x1077aa2bd] 1-20
        20  ??? [0x1077b9a74] 1-20
          20  Unsafe_Park + 126 (libjvm.dylib + 5773339) [0x106d8181b] 1-20
            20  Parker::park(bool, long) + 512 (libjvm.dylib + 4747794) [0x106c87212] 1-20
              20  __psynch_cvwait + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 105606) [0x7fffac589c86] 1-20
               *20  psynch_cvcontinue + 0 (pthread + 39138) [0xffffff7f810c88e2] 1-20

  Thread 0x1d965            20 samples (1-20)         priority 31 (base 31)
  <thread QoS default (requested default), process unclamped, process received importance donation from WindowServer [158], process received importance donation from EmojiFunctionRowIM_Extension [403], IO tier 0>
  20  thread_start + 13 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 12797) [0x7fffac6721fd] 1-20
    20  _pthread_start + 286 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 14839) [0x7fffac6729f7] 1-20
      20  _pthread_body + 180 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 15019) [0x7fffac672aab] 1-20
        20  java_start(Thread*) + 246 (libjvm.dylib + 4761518) [0x106c8a7ae] 1-20
          20  GangWorker::loop() + 179 (libjvm.dylib + 6063381) [0x106dc8515] 1-20
            20  Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 375 (libjvm.dylib + 4604309) [0x106c64195] 1-20
              20  Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 168 (libjvm.dylib + 4603692) [0x106c63f2c] 1-20
                20  ParkCommon(ParkEvent*, long) + 42 (libjvm.dylib + 4601430) [0x106c63656] 1-20
                  20  os::PlatformEvent::park() + 192 (libjvm.dylib + 4744522) [0x106c8654a] 1-20
                    20  __psynch_cvwait + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 105606) [0x7fffac589c86] 1-20
                     *20  psynch_cvcontinue + 0 (pthread + 39138) [0xffffff7f810c88e2] 1-20

  Thread 0x1d966            20 samples (1-20)         priority 31 (base 31)
  <thread QoS default (requested default), process unclamped, process received importance donation from WindowServer [158], process received importance donation from EmojiFunctionRowIM_Extension [403], IO tier 0>
  20  thread_start + 13 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 12797) [0x7fffac6721fd] 1-20
    20  _pthread_start + 286 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 14839) [0x7fffac6729f7] 1-20
      20  _pthread_body + 180 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 15019) [0x7fffac672aab] 1-20
        20  java_start(Thread*) + 246 (libjvm.dylib + 4761518) [0x106c8a7ae] 1-20
          20  GangWorker::loop() + 179 (libjvm.dylib + 6063381) [0x106dc8515] 1-20
            20  Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 375 (libjvm.dylib + 4604309) [0x106c64195] 1-20
              20  Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 168 (libjvm.dylib + 4603692) [0x106c63f2c] 1-20
                20  ParkCommon(ParkEvent*, long) + 42 (libjvm.dylib + 4601430) [0x106c63656] 1-20
                  20  os::PlatformEvent::park() + 192 (libjvm.dylib + 4744522) [0x106c8654a] 1-20
                    20  __psynch_cvwait + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 105606) [0x7fffac589c86] 1-20
                     *20  psynch_cvcontinue + 0 (pthread + 39138) [0xffffff7f810c88e2] 1-20

  Thread 0x1d967            20 samples (1-20)         priority 31 (base 31)
  <thread QoS default (requested default), process unclamped, process received importance donation from WindowServer [158], process received importance donation from EmojiFunctionRowIM_Extension [403], IO tier 0>
  20  thread_start + 13 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 12797) [0x7fffac6721fd] 1-20
    20  _pthread_start + 286 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 14839) [0x7fffac6729f7] 1-20
      20  _pthread_body + 180 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 15019) [0x7fffac672aab] 1-20
        20  java_start(Thread*) + 246 (libjvm.dylib + 4761518) [0x106c8a7ae] 1-20
          20  GangWorker::loop() + 179 (libjvm.dylib + 6063381) [0x106dc8515] 1-20
            20  Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 375 (libjvm.dylib + 4604309) [0x106c64195] 1-20
              20  Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 168 (libjvm.dylib + 4603692) [0x106c63f2c] 1-20
                20  ParkCommon(ParkEvent*, long) + 42 (libjvm.dylib + 4601430) [0x106c63656] 1-20
                  20  os::PlatformEvent::park() + 192 (libjvm.dylib + 4744522) [0x106c8654a] 1-20
                    20  __psynch_cvwait + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 105606) [0x7fffac589c86] 1-20
                     *20  psynch_cvcontinue + 0 (pthread + 39138) [0xffffff7f810c88e2] 1-20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the same problem on Windows and Ubuntu with Eclipse NEON and Jboss Tools plugin 4.4.2-FINAL

It's a [plug-in bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-23757?workflowName=GIT%20Pull%20Request%20workflow%20&stepId=4).

Solved with version 4.4.3-AM2

Comment: I see the Eclipse Market Place only has Jboss Tools plugin 4.4.2-FINAL. How do you install 4.4.3-AM2?

Comment: You can wait that become stable and published in marketplace or have a look to the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/q/41997990/5841817

Comment: Thank you. Just saw the link.

Answer (score 4):

I fix it by disabling all the plugins on startup.
Windows > Preferences >Startup and Shutdown
--> Disabled all plugin in "Plug-ins actived on startup" section.
Save & restart Eclipse.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. Every time I restart Eclipse, I have to create a new workspace, otherwise it just hangs on Registering Listeners. (I have all Plugins switched off).

Comment: I have read the following, that there is a known bug with JBoss, and they have a fix. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-23757?workflowName=GIT%20Pull%20Request%20workflow%20&stepId=4 . My only issue is I don't know how to implement the fix on Wildfly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997990/thread-deadlock-when-starting-eclipse

Comment: For me it was sufficiant to disable the startup of **JBoss AS, WildFly & EAP Server Tools UI Plugin** and **JBoss Tools Foundation Checkup** plugins.