# How to install a plugin update that's not on eclipse marketplace

Tags: eclipse, jboss, wildfly-10

I am using MacOS Sierra with Eclipse Neon2 and WIldfly10.

I am having problems when I start Eclipse, it hangs. I have the exact same symptoms as [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-23757?workflowName=GIT%20Pull%20Request%20workflow%20&stepId=4). In the link, JBoss say it is a deadlock with the JBoss server, and they have a fix for it (see 4th comment) and they provide links to [/jbosstools/neon/staging/updates](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/neon/staging/updates/).

**Question**

I have Eclipse and JBoss Wildfly installed. How do I apply this "fix" to my environment?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem under Ubuntu with Eclipse Neon2.

You have to upgrade JBoss plugin following info provided here:

- https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/neon/4.4.3.AM2.html#update_site

Inside Eclipse: *Help* > *Install New Software…* > Work with:

Then add the URL provided and go ahead installing all JBoss related upgrades.